# Removing white space from dropdown menu of navbar

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, navbar

I am trying to remove the white space in the dropdown menu. I have tried padding:0 and margin:0, but both do not seem to work. I am currently using Bootstrap 3.3.7.

My HTML:

[HTML Navbar code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkyVN.jpg)

My CSS:

```
.topnav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: transparent;
    opacity: 0.7;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    border: none;
}

.topnav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

.topnav li {
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.topnav li a {
    width: 150px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.topnav li ul li a {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 8px;
}
```

[White Space in Navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkyVN.jpg)

Comment: Are you using bootstrap..?

Comment: @hyji You need to share a snippet with the issue, the provided CSS is just not enough

Comment: I think the problem code is in your ``<ul>`` style provide your ``ul`` style code to solve the problem